# Is it possible to structure document for XML in QuarkXPress?

Tags: quarkxpress

I need to tag elements of the QuarkXPress document with tags defined in XML DTD, so later on I should be able to export data to XML file.

I know that this is possible and fairly easy done with InDesign (this article covers this topic - [Structure documents for XML](https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/structuring-documents-xml.html)). But I was unable to find such feature in Quark.

Does QuarkXPress offers such functionality or is there a plugin available that implements it?